# Google Sheet day() formula returns wrong day name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I want to get the day of the week from a specific date in Google Sheets.

I have a date in cell `B1` with a custom number format "yyyy-mm-dd": `2020-03-31`

In `A1` I have the formula `=day(B1)` which returns `Tuesday`, which is correct.

However, when I apply the same formula to the date `2020-04-01` the result of the formula is `Sunday` which is wrong.  The correct day of the week is `Wednesday`

[image: screenshot of the issue]

What is causing this and how can I address it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

=TEXT("2020-04-01","dddd") <----------- will result in Wednesday

=TEXT("2020-04-01","ddd") <----------- will result in Wed

**or with a specific field determined**

=TEXT(D1,"dddd") <----------- will result in Wednesday

=TEXT(D1,"ddd") <----------- will result in Wed

dddd = **Long Day Name**

ddd = **Short Day Name**

Answer (score 0):

1. Your formula `=DAY(d`) extracts the day number from the date `d`.

   ```
   |    date    | day number |
   |------------|------------|
   | 2020-03-31 |     31     |
   | 2020-04-01 |     01     |
   ```
2. When you then format the day number as `dddd`, Sheets coerces it to a valid date:

   ```
   |    date    | day number |  "dddd" Formatted    |
   |------------|------------|----------------------|
   | 2020-03-31 |     31     | 1900-01-30 (Tuesday) |
   | 2020-04-01 |     01     | 1899-12-31 (Sunday)  |
   ```
3. If you want to see only the day of the week from a date then apply the `"dddd"` formatting to *that* number don't apply it to the day number.  Without knowing the month and year it's impossible to know what weekday a date falls on.